# Excel VBA - Function to Detect Invalid Reference

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba

I am new to excel vba. Is there any function that would detect the cell value as `#REF!`?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `CellReference` references a cell,

To detect *any* error, use `If IsError(CellReference) Then`

To detect `#REF!` specifically use `If CellReference = CVErr(xlErrRef) Then`